# How do you enable compiz effects on ubuntu with nvidia and xinerama enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, compiz

Is it just that Nvidia doesn't support the compiz effects across multiple screens yet, or am I missing something?

When using multiple monitors on ubuntu (Karmic), if I enable the xinerama option, then all the sudden compiz is disabled. Anyone know how to enable it?

Comment: Any answer will do...really :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, it would require a hack. I've been trying to figure this out for months, as I grew accustomed to having Compiz-Fusion effects and a smooth OpenGL desktop to work with on my old dual-monitor setup with nVidia Twinview. Now I'm forced to use Xinerama with my 3-monitor setup, and I'm unable to enjoy Compiz-Fusion.

It's driving me nuts. The more this issue comes up, the more likely it is that someone will develop improved support for multiple monitors. I recommend posting on the Ubuntu and nVidia forums, and if there is a Xinerama forum, there too.

-Nachturnal

Comment: EEEeiiinteresting...bery enteresting. Thanks.