# Ubuntu 16.04 Multi-Head + Xinerama + Compiz General Performance Proplems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, xinerama

Alright, so I ran into a problem, I have two Nvidia Cards one of them which is integrated.

I have configured Xorg on the Nvidia property drivers and used nvidia-xconfig and nvidia-settings to configure my triple monitor setup, I have three separate X screens running on each monitor with Xinerama enabled with my i3 setup.

When I did finally get it to run it works for the most part but gtk programs either do not show up when I drag them onto my other screens or they just crash completely, which is a pain when I do decide to use any graphical programs on my main monitor.

Second part of my problem is when I enable compiz all programs seem to be very laggy when opening and moving across the screens.

My question is how I would be able to use Compiz with Xinerama to work well across all my monitors and why programs like spoitfy and steam done display when I move them off of my integrated graphics card.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://superuser.com/questions/82409/how-do-you-enable-compiz-effects-on-ubuntu-with-nvidia-and-xinerama-enabled?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have, although it was voted for, did not help at all.